# Pointwise Convergence of Fourier series - Dirichlet theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Our goal is to prove the following theorem(due to Dirichlet):

If $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $t_{0} \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and has right and left-sided limits at $t_{0}$ and if the left and right side generalized derivatives $$f_{R}^{'}(t_{0}) = \lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}^{+}}\frac{f(t) - f(t_{0}^{+})}{t - t_{0}}, f_{L}^{'}(t_{0}) = \lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}^{-}}\frac{f(t) - f(t_{0}^{-})}{t - t_{0}}$$

both exist, then 
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}c_{n}(f)e^{-nt_{0}} = \frac {f(t_{0}^{+}) + f(t_{0}^{-})}{2}. $$

(a)Write $S_{n}(t_{0}) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n} c_{n}(f)e^{-nt_{0}}$ as a convolution $S_{n}(t_{0}) = f*D_{n}(t_{0}).$ What is $D_{n}$?

I think the index $k$ in the summation is wrong as the summed value does not contain $k$ at all. am I right? why here in the partial sum definition the exponential does not contain the imaginary i, is it a mistake or no?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the definition of $c_n(f)$ as an integral, and then trying to write $S_n(t_0)$ as a convolution? By the way, I object to your notation $\sum_{n \in Z}$. Nothing in that notation shows that you're taking the limit of $\sum_{-n}^n$ as $n \to +\infty$ instead of, say, $\sum_{-n}^{2n}$.

Comment: No , I did not try ...... ok I will do and I will revise my notation, thank you for your advice :)

Comment: I assume that $c_n(f)$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient, right?

Comment: Yes $c_n(f)$ are the Fourier coefficients and $D_n$ is the Dirichlet kernel. What you need to know is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence which appears naturally from $(f - f(0)) \ast D_n(0)$, writing $D_n$ in its $\frac{\sin}{\sin}$ form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel

Comment: @Masacroso  yes right.

Comment: "... why it is the pointwise convergence of Fourier series and not the uniform...". The uniform limit of contiuous functions is continuous. Jump point $\implies$ no uniform convergence.

Comment: @user49640  I did not see how your new notation will correct the misunderstanding in my notation..... could you clarify please?

Comment: @user49640  $c_{n}(f)$ as an integral is written as $$c_{n}(f) = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \overline{g_{n}(x)} dx = <f,g_{n}>$$, but writing $S_{n}(t_{0})$ as a convolution .... I do not know how, could you give me a hint?

Comment: I think you are correct, it should be $S_{n}(t_{0}) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n} c_{k}(f)e^{-ikt_{0}}$

Comment: Have a look here: https://books.google.com/books?id=1WY6u0C_jEsC&pg=PA620

Comment: Please correct the formulas in your question, $e^{-nt_0}$ makes no sense.

Comment: @zhw  it is a question given by my professor (may be it is a misprint)   and if you read my question above you will see that I felt that there is a mistake and I am asking if there must exist an imaginary i or no ..... I am asking about this.